# Can Monistat improve hair growth?

Tags: alternative-medicine, hair

I was surprised to read in a Long Hair Care forum that people who spray diluted Monistat (the yeast-infection treatment!) onto their scalp significantly increases and accelerates hair growth. I can't imagine what the mechanism is. Is there any reason to think this could be true? Could bacteria be a reason for slow hair growth?

Many example claims:

- http://forums.longhaircommunity.com/showthread.php?t=2144
- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090513211653AAqnTUs
- http://www.curlycopia.com/natural-hair-experts/doctors-den/can-monistat-increase-your-hair-growth-fact-of-fiction/

Comment: Monistat is antifungal, not antibacterial. It kills **yeast** which is a fungus, not a bacteria.

Comment: I have also seen this claim, and wondered about this very question. Many people swear by it.